# How to prevent Freya to try to connect to a specific WiFi network?

Tags: wifi, networking

I have annoying issue that my laptop is always trying to connect to my neighbour's WiFi which although it has a very weak signal strength always beats my access point placed in the same room with the laptop.

Please don't answer that I should go and edit connections and remove "connect automatically" on that particular network because that works only with the networks that my laptop had been connected to previously which is not the case here.

I've searched the web but doesn't seem to be able to find any answer for my predicament.

Comment: I don't understand your question completly, does your neighbour's WiFi have the same name?

Comment: as @Rafael points out, it would be great if you could add some information - I wonder what is actually *happening* as well, because your laptop isn't supposed to automatically connect to anything.

Comment: Your computer shouldn't attempt to connect to your neighbour's wifi if it requires authentication, and if it does then it would succeed and so you could go and remove “connect automatically”. Is this some kind of access point with a default name (e.g. named after the ISP)? Does it require authentication?

Comment: It tries to connect but isn't in your remembered networks list? You don't need to successfully connect for it to be remembered, just accidentally clicked once.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. What is happening is that my laptop is trying to connect to other wifi first. The other wifi is password protected so I click Cancel, go to wifi networks and manually select my wifi. The other wifi does not have the same name as mine.
And yes, that is the most interesting part, my laptop is automatically trying to connect to other wifi even though it has never been connected to that wifi and the other wifi is not listed in remembered network list.

Comment: I suggest reporting this as a bug. I'm not sure however if to close the question, as my answer *might* be useful to someone else with a similar problem, but not this exact issue. I'll leave this one to the community to decide.

Answer (score 3):

If it shows up in your network connection list, then just select and click delete.

[image]

This should stop it from connecting automatically until/unless you attempt to connect again manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I explained in my question my laptop was never connected to other wifi so that wifi is not shown is network connections, therefore I cannot delete it.

Comment: @WebShaped.Biz this sounds like a bug, if I'm not mistaken, as network-manager usually requires you to choose to connect to a network the first time it is discovered.

Comment: Thanx @RolandiXor. What's more confusing is that the occurrence of this issue is far more frequent when my laptop is starting from suspend than when it's just booting from shut down.

Comment: just FYI I can delete networks that I never connected to (showing as 'never') without any issue, so it is most likely a bug